# Angular5: Router param with regex

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I want have two component on the same route. One is having '-offers' at the end. Both route is having dynamic url params.

below is an example.

1. domain/student/books-offer  -- to the books offer component
2. domain/student/exam1    -- to the exam page

I tried with different solution using urlMatcher but none working. I want to give two different router component. Below what I tried to give in app.routes but not worked.

```
{ path: 'student/:id["-offers"]', loadChildren: './student-offers/student-offers.module#StudentsOffersModule' },
{ path: 'student/:id', loadChildren: './students-exams/students-exams.module#StudentsExamModule' },
```

Comment: Can you use?{ path: 'student/:id/offers, ...}  //example domain/student/type/offers { path: 'student/:id',...}         //example domain/student/type

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you do it wrong.

```
{ path: 'student/:item/offers', loadChildren: './student-offers/student-offers.module#StudentsOffersModule' },
{ path: 'student/exam/:id', loadChildren: './students-exams/students-exams.module#StudentsExamModule' },
```

It works when you respect the conventions and syntax.

By the way, it's a lazy loading strategy, not a routing one. So don't expect it to work.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: As I said book is dynamic and exam1 is dynamic as well. possible url can be . laptop-offers, mobile-offers, exam1, exam2. All should serve from /student/

Comment: @Shabbir, you can not. For Angular is the same /student/what-ever. You can use a component parent of StudentsOffers and StuddensExam and with a *ngIf make visible one or another depending Router.path